# Groovy method reference for multiple instances

Tags: groovy, easybind

I am migrating from Java to Groovy and having an issue with method references.

In Java, I could do this:

```
Function<Bean, String> f = Bean::method;
String s = f.apply(new Bean());
```

I want to implement the same functionality in Groovy. I tried doing:

```
Function f = Bean.&method
Sting s = f.apply new Bean()
```

But I got an exception, on the `f.apply` line:

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: Bean.method() is applicable for argument types: (Bean) values: [Bean@17483c58]
```

I know I can do the following to get the method reference for an instance method, but I want to get a generic method for any instance.

```
MethodClosure f = bean.&method
String s = f()
```

I want to use this to use the EasyBind library. It allows you to select a JavaFX property with a Function reference. You might have a hierarchy of classes and properties, and to select them, you might do:

```
property.bind(EasyBind.select(root).select(Root::branch).selectObject(Branch::leaf));
```

So when any of the values in the tree change, `property` get's updated with the correct value.

I am able to replace the `Bean.&method` with `{bean -> bean.method}` and that works fine. In Java, the `Bean::method` is actually an alias-type thing for `bean -> bean.method`.

Comment: AFAIK it's impossible. Would work for static methods only.

Comment: @Opal That discourages me from using Groovy for what I am doing then :/

Comment: Maybe give us a broader context?

Comment: I updated my question with the use.

Comment: I think you should post your solution as an answer. It looks fine. You could also go with `{ it.method }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
MethodClosure f = { it.method }
String s = f()
```